# React routing is not working, it is getting refreshed on every page click

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, custom-component

We are trying to add react routing V6 ino one of our custom component called **NAVIGATION**( we are adding it as a dependency as package.json)

In this Navigation component we can add multiple tabs as shown below
In below code we have implemented react routing for all these tabs.

so our **expectation is to go to any tab(i.e Home->ContactUs->AboutUs) without page refresh, But it is getting refreshed on every tab click,we have to go to any tab without refresh using router**

Plese give some suggestion to overcome from this problem, any guidance or input will be helpful

[react](/questions/tagged/react)

testNav.json

```
[
   {
     "id" : "testNav-1",
     "text" : "Home",
     "href" :"/"
   }
   {
     "id" : "testNav-1",
     "text" : "ContactUs",
     "href" :"/ContactUs"
   }
   {
     "id" : "testNav-1",
     "text" : "AboutUs",
     "href" :"/AboutUs"
   }
]
```

I have written following code

```
<div>
<BrowseRouter>
     <NavigationTab>
        firstNav={{
         fstText : 'primary navigation'
         Links : testNav
    </NavigationTab>
    <Routes>
       <Route path='/' element={<Home/>}><Route>
       <Route path='contactUs' element={<ContactUs/>}><Route>
       <Route path='aboutUs' element={<AboutUs/>}><Route>
    </Routes>
</BrowseRouter>
<div>
```

Comment: What tabs are being clicked? Something in the `Navigation` component? Can you [edit] the post to include all relevant code as part of your [mcve]? I suspect you are rendering raw anchor (`<a href/>`) tags. Side note, `contactUs` and `aboutUs` are not valid React components, they should be [capitalized](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized), e.g. `ContactUs` and `AboutUs`.

Comment: Can you add the `Navigation` component code to your post so we can see how you are navigating between tabs?

Answer (score 0):

You are using BrowseRouter instead of BrowserRouter, the correct spelling is BrowserRouter.

```
 <BrowserRouter>
  <NavigationTab
  firstNav={{
  fstText: "primary navigation",
  Links: testNav
}}
/>
<Routes>
<Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
<Route path="/contactUs" element={<ContactUs />} />
<Route path="/aboutUs" element={<AboutUs />} />
</Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```